# How to add two inputs from the same forms in the same collection field in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper

Im working on the tutorial meteor has for my first app. So i wanted to extend it a bit more and have two text boxes, one for comments and one for rating lets say.
The problem is that i cant get correctly the values from both forms (actually cant get the rating value at all) in order to save them in my database and furthermore the enter-submit feature stopped working.

My .js code for body events is:

```
Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function(event) {
        // Prevent default browser form submit
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get value from form element
        var text = event.target.text.value;
        var rating = event.target.rating.value;

        // Insert a task into the collection
        Meteor.call("addTask", text, rating);

        // Clear form
        event.target.text.value = "";

    }
});
```

For add task:

```
AddTask: function(text, rating) {
    //.....
    Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        username: Meteor.user().username,
        rating: rating
    });
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<form class="new-task">
    <h2>What is happening?</h2>
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Share your experience!" />
    <h2>Rating:</h2>
    <input type="text" name="rating" placeholder="insert your rating!" />
</form>
```

---

```
<template name="task">
    <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
        {{#if isOwner}}
        <button class="delete">&times;</button>
        {{/if}}
        <span class="text"><strong>{{username}}</strong> - {{text}}- {{rating}}</span>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Not sure what your file names are, but `Template.body.events` may be throwing things off unless your template is named `body`.

Comment: Like `<template name="body"> ~ some stuff ~ </template>`

Comment: If it's task, it'd need to be something like `Template.task.events`

Comment: I dont have a template named body but neither meteor's code has and it works fine. the only additions i did were:
    1) var rating = event.target.rating.value;
    2) <h2>Rating:</h2>
  <input type="text" name="rating" placeholder="insert your rating!" />
    3)rating:rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Meteor method `addTask` is not defined. Call `Meteor.call("AddTask", text, rating);` instead, or rename your method to `addTask`.

For example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.events({
        'click button': function () {
            Meteor.call("addTask", "1", 2, function(error){
                if (error) alert(error.reason);
            });
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        addTask: function (text, rating) {
            check(text, String);
            check(rating, Number);
            console.log(text);
            console.log(rating);
        }
    });
}
```